# Масштабирование векторного изображения в Switch до размеров текста

Tags: android, android-switch

Пытаюсь в Switch перед текстом вставить векторную картинку флага.

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/flag_europe_germany"
    android:text="Германия" />
```

Изначальный размер векторного изображения flag_europe_germany - 640х480. В итоге изображение растягивается до своих размеров. Как сделать, чтобы оно масштабировалось до размеров текста?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутри вашего `@drawable/flag_europe_germany` есть свойства, попробуйте их поизменять.

```
android:height="48dp" 
android:viewportHeight="24" 
android:viewportWidth="24" 
android:width="48dp"
```

Очень интересно и подробно про это [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/company/rambler-co/blog/267073/). Также [документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html).